# My Axios GET function get called repeatedly

Tags: reactjs, axios

Here is my code.

```js
function Customer() {

    var nextCustID = 0
    const [nextCustIDList, setNextCustIDList] = useState([]) 

    const getNextCustID = () => {
        Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/api/getNextCustID").then(response => {
          setNextCustIDList(response.data);
        })
    }
```

...

I can see in my server that handle the call showing the above 'get' were calling repeatedly.

Thanks

Comment: Hi All, any idea how to resolve that? Thanks

Comment: Have you ruled out the `Customer` function itself being called repeatedly?

Comment: Hi Andy,  I think it's not the case. If I change the setNextCustIDList(reponse.data) with console.log(response.data), then the Axios were only called once. Thanks

Comment: Where are you calling `getNextCustID()`? Would it happen to be in a `useEffect` hook with `nextCustIDList` as a dependency?

Comment: Hi Andy, It's called from here.  I'm not using useEffect in this code.
    if ( pathname === '/customers-new' ) {
        custHeading = 'Add new customer';
        func = 'new';
        getNextCustID();
        nextCustIDList.map((val) => { nextCustID = val.nextcust });
        console.log(nextCustID);
    }

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69624206/edit) to include more code. It does not belong in the comments

Comment: Hi Andy, I create a test code which show similar issue.  import React, { useImperativeHandle, useState } from 'react';
import Axios from 'axios';

function Test () {
    const pathname = window.location.pathname

    var nextCustID = ''
    const [nextCustIDList, setNextCustIDList] = useState([]) 

    const getNextCustID = () => {
        Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/api/getNextCustID").then(response => {
          setNextCustIDList(response.data);
        })
    }

Comment: Sorry, I have to send twice as the comment box have limit on number of characters

Comment: if ( pathname === '/customers-new' ) {
        getNextCustID();
        nextCustIDList.map((val) => { nextCustID = val.nextcust });
        console.log(nextCustID);
    }

 
    return (

        <div>
            <h1>Hello</h1>
        </div>
    )


}

export default Test;

Comment: Hi Phil. sorry, just saw your comment. yes, send the test code which show similar issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are calling the request call method in function, the problem is when 'setting' the state (setNextCustIDList), the re-render happen and again your function getting execuated and leading to infinite loop.

```
  const getNextCustID = () => {
  };

  getNextCustID();
```

Try some thing like below, wrapping in `useEffect`. (empty dependency array causes one time execution)

```js
const Customer = () => {
  var nextCustID = 0;
  const [nextCustIDList, setNextCustIDList] = React.useState([]);

  const getNextCustID = () => {
    fetch("http://localhost:3001/api/getNextCustID")
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("Success");
        setNextCustIDList(response.data);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log("Error");
        setNextCustIDList([]);
      });
  };

  React.useEffect(() => getNextCustID(), []);

  return <div> Hello {nextCustIDList} </div>;
};


ReactDOM.render(<Customer />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: @david, Great!. Please you may accept the answer for benefit of future readers.